# Getting an element from XSL that creates HTML, from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, xslt

I have an asp:xml tag that holds XSL Information:

```
<asp:xml id="XmlMetadataFields"  TransformSource="ShowClientTypesPerItemActivity.xsl" ></asp:xml>
```

Inside this XSL, there's some code that produces HTML. The bit that's relevant here:

```
<xsl:when test="@FieldTypeID = 5">
    <input type="checkbox">
        <xsl:if test="Visibility = 0">
            <xsl:attribute name="hidden">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Visibility"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            DefValue<xsl:value-of select="@FieldID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            DefValue<xsl:value-of select="@FieldID" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="Value = true">
            <xsl:attribute name="checked">
                <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </input>
</xsl:when>
```

a Javascript function tries to call HTML inside this XSL:

```
if(document.all["DefValue639"].checked)
```

The thing is, the javascript does not find the elements inside the XSL. When I right cliked the HTML Page output to the client, I can't find the output either(Couldn't find DefValue anywhere).

How do I access the XSL from Javascript? Have I completely misunderstood something?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the xls? A typical use of an xsl is to transform for example pure xml to html.

Comment: That's what this XSL does - it sort of outputs HTMLat least that's what the browser can see, although I can't see the HTML Code when right clicking "View source". BTW, in Chrome I can't even see the checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to actually access the XSL itself, or HTML that is producted by overlaying the XSL onto the XML?

Comment: Also, what happens when you doa  view->source on the generated code. Do you see the 'id' here. And, don't use `document.all`, use `document.getElementById()`

Comment: It seems that the XSLT transformation is intended to be performed on the server side -- not on the client. Therefore, don't worry how to perform an XSLT transformation using Javascript. The real question is whether this transformation was performed on the server-side and why its result was not output. The answer can only be found by looking at the appropriate ASP.NET code, which you haven't shown to us.

Comment: Eventually I found the ID in the HTML - the regular view source in ie doesn't show this, only when hitting F12 I can see the ID. So now, I have a page which has this HTML Element with the correct ID - but the Javascript can't find the element that was created after the page was loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the `input`-tag like this in order to set the attributes:

```
<xsl:element name="input">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">checkbox</xsl:attribute>
    ...
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some unknown reason the checkbox became a textbox. I double checked that I did everything correct, and even the HTML that's in the output is written as checkbox, but it's displayed as textbox.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the output?

Comment: While pasting the output here, I found the problem. The XSL added white spacing in the output, since I wrote it with spacing between the lines of the XSL.
Thanks!